# Unable to factory reset my HTC Desire S

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, factory-reset, htc-desire-s

I have a HTC Desire S. I have firmware updates but when i try to update the same. I rebooted in the updating process and the phone hangs there for hour (i waited for 4 hrs once). I tried to factory reset the mobile, still facing the same issue.

Note: The phone is rooted.

Do I need to visit HTC Service center or is there anything that I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory reset only resets all user data, not the OS itself. If your update failed for some reason, you'd have to reflash the phone. You can find info on this in the [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1186401) forum.

Note that since your phone is rooted, your warranty may be void. Take this into consideration before you take your phone to the service center.